# WScript http post/get em JScript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, batch

estou afim de fazer um script em JScript para ser executado pelo WScript(processador de comandos nativo do Windows)...

E tenho uma dúvida: Como faço para enviar dados em POST ou GET(como em um formulário) para uma página PHP?

Desde já, agradeço.

Edit:
Galera a ideia é fazer uma conexão com um DB usando uma página PHP na web, e utilizando um script local no computador...Alguém?

Comment: você tem o form ai?

Comment: Não tem form...Na verdade é um arquivo .js que é executado pelo WScript diretamente no Windows! Não é em uma página Web.

Comment: Para funcionar vc precisa saber pelo menos o nome dos campos para enviar para a pagina php. É possível fazer isso com powershell, é mais simples.

Comment: rray me ensina por powershell, pois usando o WScript posso criar um objeto shell e usar suas funções. Enquanto aos campos, podem ser username e password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No powershell existe um cmdlet específico para criar requisições o [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) está disponível a partir da versão 3.

### Exemplo com get

Para enviar um requisição simples por basta:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost/teste.php?param1=valor1&param2=valor&param3=valor3"
```

E digamos que a página php tenha o seguinte código:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_GET);
```

A saída console é mostrada na figura, várias informaçõe são mostradas e podem ser manipuladas como o `content` que é o retorno do servidor, statusCode etc.

[image: console get]

### Exemplo com post

Para criar uma requisição por post é necessários saber quais campos devem ser enviados para o arquivo de backend, isso pode ser obtido pelo atriuto `name` dos campos do form. Outro ponto importante, as informações são enviadas no corpo da requisição, será necessário criar um hash(chave/valor) e informar o método, por padrão todas requisições são get.

```
$campos = @{"usuario" = "admin"; "senha"=2015}
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost/teste.php" -Method Post -Body $campos
```

Arquivo de login:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['usuario'] == 'admin' && $_POST['senha'] == '2015'){
        echo 'Logado como administrador';
    }else{
        echo 'você não privilegios suficientes';
    }
```

Retorno do console:

[image: console post]

Comment: Vlw cara. Só tem uma coisa...Existe alguma forma de executar scripts do powershell em outros computadores sem ter que liberar o uso? Algo como um .bat que executa em qualquer PC(Mesmo que tenha limitações no script)...Se não der, como faço para liberar no meu PC? Até.

Comment: @Superbomber, vc diz a restrição de segurança?

Comment: Sim, existe como eu executar um script do Powershell sem precisar desativar essa restrição?(mesmo que fique limitado) E se não tiver como, como desativo no meu PC?

Comment: @Superbomber você pode rodar `Set-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted` isso remove todas as restrições, tem um outro jeito de passar ela no arquivo, ainda estou vendo isso.