# É possível manipular Header de request http?

Tags: aplicação-web, http-request, http-headers

Tratado-se de uma requisição `http`, é possível realizar a manipulação do cabeçalho do `request`? Ou somente é possível fazer tal manipulação no `response`? Se for possível, em quais linguagens em consigo? Existe algum exemplo que possa elucidar melhor o entendimento?

Comment: Sim, você pode montar um requisição com qualquer campo que desejar, como por exemplo enviar um `user-agent` com valor `qualquer coisa`, exemplo => pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38725/91. [exemplo em powershel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90543/91) mais simples. Uma das utilidades é automatizar cadastros de formularios em lote, uma vez que seja sabido quais campos enviar.

Comment: @rray, muito obrigado, encontrei com JQuery também é possível realizar tal manipulação com `ajax` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Acabei de encontrar, vou fazer alguns testes. Uma dúvida, o que seria cadastro de formulários em lote?

Comment: Digamos que vc tenha que cadastrar os 200 novos produtos que chegaram, porém não tem acesso ao banco de dados, fazer 200 vezes o mesmo processo não é bom, o que pode ser feito é criar um script com os valores já formatados(cada valor associado com respectivo campo) e enviar as 200 requisições e problema resolvido. Isso não se aplica a todos os sistemas alguns tem mecanismos para evitar ou dificultar isso, seja através de um tolken, captcha etc.

Comment: Entendi, eu não conhecia por este nome. Quando eu preciso fazer este tipo de tarefa, utilizo o`AutoIt` (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Me quebra bastante o galho, rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é possível sim!

Atualmente existe diversas linguagens que você pode modificar o Header: **C, Pyton, Java, PHP, Javascript**... e também existe algo interessante, ainda mais tratando de segurança, de uma olhada em:

[Linux Kali](https://www.kali.org/)

Nesse sistema existem ferramentas de teste de segurança, básicos ao avançados, você pode modificar o cabeçalho ou montar uma sequencia de ataque, etc.. para testar, se o alvo que quer executar esse macro ou AutoIt como você diz, for seu, você não terá problemas em criar um bot para o mesmo, caso não, você pode ter problemas, pois pode ser visto como um cracker!

OBS: Teste apenas em domínios que você é o administrador ou dono!

Ferramentas para uso:

- Burpsuite
- Commix
- Httptrack
- Entre outros...

é isso, boa sorte e bons estudos!